# read a .h264 file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'll be happy for your help with some problem that I have.

**Goal:** To read a .h264 file (I extracted the raw bitstream to a file using ffmpeg) using python, and save it in some data structure (probably a list, I'll be happy for suggestions).

I want to read the data as hexa, for example I'll show how the data looks like:
[image]

What I want is to feed  each byte(2 hexa digits), into a list, or some other data structure.
But any step forward will help me.

**My Attempts:**
First I tried to read the way I know:

```
with open(path, 'r') as fp:
     data = fp.read()
```

Didn't work, got just ".

After a lot of changes, I tried something else, I saw online:

```
    with open(path, 'r') as fp:
    hex_list = ["{:02}".format(ord(c)) for c in fp.read()]
```

Still got an empty list.

I'll be happy for you help.
Thanks a lot.

**EDIT**:
Thanks to the comment below, I tried to open using 'rb', but still with no luck.

Comment: Open your file in [binary mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) : `rb` for the mode.

Comment: Thanks, but didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an h264 mp4 file, you can open it and get a hexadecimal string representation like this using [`binascii.hexlify()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.b2a_hex):

```
import binascii
with open('test.mp4', 'rb') as fin:
    hexa = binascii.hexlify(fin.read())
    print(hexa[0:1000])
```

hexa will be a python [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytearray) object, and you can easily get back the binary representation by doing `binascii.unhexlify(hexa)`. This will be much more efficient than storing the hex representation as strings in a `list()`, both in terms of space and time. You can access the `bytes` array with indices/slices, so whatever you were intending to do with the list will probably work fine with this (it will just be much faster and use a lot less memory).

One thing to keep in mind though is to get the the first hexadecimal digit from a `bytes` object, you don't do `hexa[0]`, but rather `hexa[0:1]`. To get the first pair of hexadecimal digits (byte), you do: `hexa[0:2]`. The second byte is `hexa[2:4]` etc. As explained in the [docs for `hex()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex):

> Since bytes objects are sequences of integers (akin to a tuple), for a
>   bytes object b, b[0] will be an integer, while b[0:1] will be a bytes
>   object of length 1. (This contrasts with text strings, where both
>   indexing and slicing will produce a string of length 1)